# Countif and vlookup on multiple sheet

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Is there a way I can count the number of occurrence of the value on Sheet1 if that value is classified as value2 on sheet2.

Here's my data:

```
Sheet1:

User1
User1
User2
User2
User3
User1

Sheet2:

user1   Old
user2   New
user3   New
```

So basically I just want to count the occurence of all users that are new.

So if I have the right formula, it will return 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the users in `column A` of `sheet 1` and the other data in `column A` and `B` of `sheet 3`,

Use an `INDEX` `MATCH` formula to retrieve all the types from `sheet 3` to `sheet 1`. Use the below formula in `column B` of `sheet 1` and drag it down,

`=INDEX(Sheet3!A:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet3!A:A,0),2)`

Now you have to just count the number of "new" in the `column B`,

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"new")`

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I've done that as a workaround. So there is no way I can get the count without creating a new column or using VBA?

Comment: @RosVergel Yes, if you need a count, it has to be somewhere in the sheet. so a column is required. May be with VBA its not required.